# angular 2+ convert gmt datetime to another timezone

Tags: angular, timezone, angular2-services, timezone-offset

In angular 2 with webpack and ts, What is the best way to convert a date string say `'2017-07-07 12:00:11'` which is in GMT to say, IST by giving the offset `'+5:30'`, so the date time changes to `'2017-07-07 17:30:11'`. 
I did following but it did not work:

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

In the ts file:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

let setdate = moment(); // today date
console.log('timezone date=', setdate);

setdate.tz("GMT").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(setdate.tz("Asia/Singapore").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

But when i create the build, i get following error:

```
Module parse failed: blah\node_modules\moment-timezone\data\packed\l
atest.json Unexpected token (2:10)
```

Will this work in angular 2 or any other way exists to do this??

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
setdate.tz("Europe/London").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

[Moment timezone Refrence](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)